# Can I get a table name from a join select resultset metadata

Tags: java, jdbc, metadata

Below is my code trying to retrieve table name form Resultset

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from product");

ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
int count = meta.getColumnCount();
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
  System.out.println(meta.getTableName(i));
}
```

But it returns empty, no mention it is a join select resultset.
Is there any other approaches to retrieve table name from reusltset metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Getting table names from ResultSetMetaData is something most DBMS's JDBC-drivers (Oracle, DB2,...) don't imlement since there are many situations where the specification doesn't define what should be returned - e.g. in case of views (view-name or base-table-name), presence of aliases (table-alias or real table-name), results of functions that take multiple or no parameters etc.

So I fear there is no way to get what you want for most DBMSs, least of all in a DBMS-independent manner.

Answer (score 0):

When you create you statement, try setting the scroll/concurrency types like so:
`conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)`

Some drivers require these settings in order to return the table name.

[See here for details](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/55e8cbb2-b11c-446e-93ab-dc30658caf99/resultsetmetadatagettablename-returns-instead-of-table-name?forum=sqldataaccess&prof=required)

Answer (score -1):

The column indices passed to getTableName() start at 1.  Change your loop to read:

```
for (int i=1; i<=count; i++) {
  System.out.println(meta.getTableName(i));
}
```